# annotate plot with linear line

Tags: pgfplots

In my code below, I wanted to add a linear dashed line like this:

[image]
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix, backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dotted,gray!50}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={gray!50!black},
             every tick label/.append style={scale=0.85}}

\begin{filecontents*}{testdata.csv}
-155.5  21.7
-152.3  21.5
-149.8  21.2
-147.2  20.8
-145.5  20.3
-143.7  19.5
-141.3  18.4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every plot/.append style={very thick}]
\begin{axis}[width=14cm,height=9cm,
                    grid = both,
                    every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.7},
                    x dir=reverse,
                    title = {},
                    xlabel={Time},
                    ylabel={Temp},
                    ]

\addplot+ [smooth,blue,name path=plotA] table[mark = none, x index=0,y index=1,col sep=space] {testdata.csv};
\draw [-latex] (-143,21.3) node[above,text width=.8cm,align=center]{\scriptsize{end of \\ linear region}} to[out=270,in=130] (-145,20.1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a function, but as x dir is reversed, it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add coordinates to the plot, like this:

```
\addplot+ [smooth,blue,name path=plotA] table[mark = none, x index=0,
y index=1,col sep=space] {testdata.csv}%
    coordinate [pos=1] (A)
    coordinate [pos=0.9] (B);
```

`1` is the end of the line, `0` is the start. So we pick two that form a line, then make it longer using a negative value for `shorten`, like

```
\draw[red,loosely dashed, very thick,shorten >=-7cm] (A) -- (B);
```

And this is the output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your elegant solution.  Can you give me some more insights as to how you calculated the position of the linear line.  I am still a little lost as to the `pos=1` and `pos=0.9`.

Comment: @Joe Sure. In TikZ, any line has various coordinates, represented from 0 to 1. 0 is the start, 1 is the end, 0.5 is the middle. 0.75 would be at 3/4 of that line, and so on. You can refer to these points with words too, like 0.5 is midway, 0 is at start, and 1 is at end. Try writing `\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) node[at start] {foo};` and replace that key with the others.

Answer (score 1):

I have calculated the linear equation with `(-143.7,19.5)` and `(-141.3,18.4)` points and I had this approximation : `y=-0.45833333333333*x-46.3625`.
Then, enter this in your `tikzpicture` : `\addplot+[red,dashed,mark=no,domain=-141.3:-147.75]{-0.45833333333333*x-46.3625};`

Full code :

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix, backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dotted,gray!50}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={gray!50!black},
             every tick label/.append style={scale=0.85}}

\begin{filecontents*}{testdata.csv}
-155.5  21.7
-152.3  21.5
-149.8  21.2
-147.2  20.8
-145.5  20.3
-143.7  19.5
-141.3  18.4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every plot/.append style={very thick}]
\begin{axis}[width=14cm,height=9cm,
                    grid = both,
                    every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.7},
                    x dir=reverse,
                    title = {},
                    xlabel={Time},
                    ylabel={Temp},
                    ]

\addplot+ [smooth,blue] table[mark = none, x index=0,y index=1,col sep=space] {testdata.csv};
\draw [-latex] (-143,21.3) node[above,text width=.8cm,align=center]{\scriptsize{end of \\ linear region}} to[out=270,in=130] (-145,20.1);
\addplot+[red,dashed,mark=no,domain=-141.3:-147.75]{-0.45833333333333*x-46.3625};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output :

[image]